# iOS: Scale up image in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, contentmode

I'm setting an image to a UIButton like this:

```
[fView.coverImage.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:MYURL] placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                        fView.coverImage.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                        [fView.coverImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}];
```

The image in question has a height of 400px. Most of the time this works fine, but on an iPad Retina screen, the UIButton has a height of around 600px. Despite the content mode I have specified, the image will not scale up beyond 400px. How can I make the image scale up beyond it's original size?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your block:

```
[ImageManipulation scale:image toSize:fView.coverImage.imageView.frame];
```

"ImageManipulation" is my class name, call it however you like..

And this is the method i use to scale:

```
+ (UIImage*)scale: (UIImage*)image toSize: (CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Hope this helps